# How to turn off the animation when locking screen on Nexus 5 running on KitKat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, nexus-5

I need to turn off the **CRT TV animation** when locking screen in Nexus 5, running KitKat 4.4.3.

I was able to turn off the TV animation by keeping **Animator duration scale** to **Animation off** in developer options, but this caused the issue in **dialer**. The dial pad won't appear first time. You have to click again to get the dial pad.

So any other way to turn off the animation without affecting dialer? The phone is not rooted, though solution for rooted phone is also welcomed.

**Update:**

The CRT TV animation animation is no longer there in Lollipop.

Comment: I know that [GravityBox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) has an option to use a fade effect instead of CRT on screenoff. Of course, this requires root and [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) but comes with a lot of great additional tweaks and improvements.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by a comment on the question itself: [GravityBox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox), a module for the famous [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) framwork, can be used for this (and for many other things: it's a feature-rich toolbox): you can select a different effect, or even switch it off.

If you're on a custom ROM, however, the dev doesn't recommend using *GravityBox*, as it might lead to conflicts (many of the tweaks *GravityBox* offers are already present in custom ROMs). In that case, simply [search the repo for other CRT related mods](http://repo.xposed.info/module-overview?combine=crt) – there are several of them dealing with this. One example would be [XBlast Tools](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ind.fem.black.xposed.mods), which explicitely mentions: *CRT Screen off effect (No Effect,Horizontal Effect and Vertical Effect)* in its list of tweaks.